# material-ui icon changing the styles of inner elements

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react with material-ui and I want to be able to change the styles of inner elements in components.
For example: the ListItem component has primaryText, leftIcon and such, and I want to change the style of the primaryText or the leftIcon and to play with the margins for example.

How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

use inline style:

```
<ListItem
    style={{color: "#f7ca18"}}
    primaryText="Hello"
    leftIcon={<ActionGrade color={"#f7ca18"} />}
/>
```